# Do Chosen-Chiphertext attacks only apply to public-key cryptosystems?

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack

Do [Chosen-Chiphertext attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-ciphertext_attack) (CCA-1/2) only apply to public-key Cryptosystem?

Answer (score 4):

No, there are also CCA games for private key encryption schemes. There you have additional encryption oracles that you can use, to obtain encryptions for messages of your choice (in a private key encryption scheme you can not encrypt yourself, because this requires the secret key).
See here for a concise explanation and comparison:
http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/IND-CCA